# Python code style - blank lines in long list

Tags: coding-style, python, whitespace

I'm curious, is there a standard approach to dealing with long lists in the Python community, and in particular, is there any antipathy toward doing blank lines followed by comments to break up a particularly long list, e.g. of tuples, or in a dict, etc.?

For example, I'm developing a GUI application in wxPython, and am defining the keyboard shortcut mappings to . Is this fairly Pythonic?

```py
accelerator_table = wx.AcceleratorTable([
    # Case accelerators
    (CTRL, ord('S'), EventIds.SAVE_CASE),
    (CTRL_SHIFT, ord('S'), EventIds.RENAME_CASE),
    (CTRL, wx.WXK_DELETE, EventIds.REMOVE_CASE),
    (CTRL_SHIFT, wx.WXK_DELETE, EventIds.DELETE_CASE),

    # Project accelerators
    (CTRL_ALT_SHIFT, ord('S'), EventIds.RENAME_PROJECT),
    (ALT, wx.WXK_DELETE, EventIds.REMOVE_PROJECT),
    (ALT_SHIFT, wx.WXK_DELETE, EventIds.DELETE_PROJECT),

    # Help accelerators
    (NORMAL, wx.WXK_F1, EventIds.HELP),
    (NORMAL, wx.WXK_F2, EventIds.LAUNCH_MANUAL),
    (NORMAL, wx.WXK_F12, EventIds.ABOUT),
    ...
])
```

The details aren't particularly important, but I'd like to write in a style that will not annoy other programmers along the way, and therefore to decide right now whether this pattern is worth keeping around.

**Edit:** Just to clarify: I'm not intending to put anything beyond that single blank line between sections in the list. That seems like it should minimize any confusion on the part of someone reading through the code.

Comment: If it makes the code easier to understand, who cares about "pythonic"?

Comment: A reasonable question. My thought was simply that "easier to read" has *some* things that are constant, but some things that vary by convention in the community. What's easier to read for a Java gal isn't necessarily the same as what's easier to read for a Python guy isn't necessarily the same as what's easier to read for a Lisp gal. Conventions aren't hard rules, but they're worth at least being aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the OP's initial approach, it is immediately obvious to me what it's doing. I don't see that there are readability or maintainability problems with this at all, nor do I see that it violates any commonly-accepted Python conventions or idioms. It's clear, and it uses minimal syntactic boilerplate and extraneous operations to achieve its goal. I recommend sticking with this approach.

The implementation suggested by [Demian's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/191579/62765) seems to create more problems than it solves. Returning a list from a property is usually not a good idea, because it creates an interface that will look identical to an attribute, but will exhibit bizarre behavior if used as such, e.g. **t.file.extend(t.project)** will *not* do what most users would expect, and will "fail silently", causing potentially confounding bugs.

The OP could use instance attributes or class fields instead of properties, but I'm not sure an object-oriented approach has much utility here (i.e. it seems to be using class syntax without employing actual OOP concepts).

But the suggestion to separate the tuple-list aggregate into multiple smaller lists, that are then concatenated and passed to **wx.AcceleratorTable**, seems sensible. The "right" approach is mostly a matter of preference, though I still prefer the OP's initial approach because it involves less list manipulation, and doesn't have any readability issues that I see.

Comment: +1, you should never make something more complex if it also makes it harder to understand for no _real_ benefit.

Comment: See my update. I wasn't thinking overly clearly when I originally answered.

Comment: @DemianBrecht: Entirely understandable; I edited my answer to reflect your update, and agree that your revised suggestion is more palatable (I was typing my answer as you were editing yours).

Answer (score 1):

[snip due to people not reading the /entire/ response]

To answer your actual question, whitespace is fine to break things up visually, but I'd recommend that the number of lines that you use should not exceed that of the number of lines between other entities in your code (such as number of lines between functions within a class, or module-level classes or functions). As Python's readability is so heavily based on whitespace, using more whitespace in a particular method to break up internal code might initially throw off a reader looking to grok it at a glance.

**Edit based on comments**:

```
>>> accel_file = [('a','b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> accel_project = [('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(accel_file, accel_project))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
```

Grouping as such allows your code to be self-documenting. `chain` is an overly complex solution in this particular case (I was writing code using at the time of the answer :P), but could be useful if doing something like:

```
accelerators = [accel_file, acces_project, ...]
list(chain(*accelerators))
```

But for the simple case, concatenation (`+`) would be preferred.

Comment: A couple thoughts: (1) I'm not sure that actually increases readability. It's abstracted things quite a bit, which can be a good thing in many cases, but in this case, I think it's *less* obvious what's going on, which I'd like to avoid, as that decreases maintainability substantially.. (2) That abstraction is a much larger step than is necessary even if we do split it up. I don't see a good reason to use a class instead of just a set of list variables, e.g. `help_accel = [(a, b, c), (d, e, f), ...]`. I'm not sure we really need to abstract a list of tuples to a class.

Comment: Also, as I noted in my edit, I certainly would never put more than a single blank line between elements (as in the list I put in my example).

Comment: @ChrisKrycho: Ah, in my un-caffeinated state, I didn't see fully what was going on. Rather than using a class, I'd still set a local reference to each logical block and then chain them to create the list being fed into ``AcceleratorTable``.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho: See edit. Really, it's just personal preference, but this makes the intention of each portion of your list easier to grok. It's /clear/ what is intended to go where (and therefore increases readability).

Comment: Sure, and that makes a lot more sense. Out of curiosity, though: why use `chain()` instead of just concatenating with `+`, e.g. `accel_file + accel_project`?

Comment: No reason in particular as they achieve the same result. Using chain, you *could* do something like ``accelerators = [accel_file, accel_project, ...]`` and then feed it into ``chain(*accelerators)``. But yes, if you're not doing something like that, then simple concat using ``+`` would be the way to go (I was working with ``chain`` when I wrote the above ;))

Comment: Would love to know the reason for the downvote :P

Comment: Good point. In this case, I think what I'm doing is simple enough that doing that would obfuscate rather than clarify, but it's certainly a useful technique in other situations. The downvote... wasn't me. (I don't have enough rep to *up* yet. Heh.)

Comment: @DemianBrecht You're increasing complexity, decreasing readability, and gaining no additional flexibility (that couldn't be done more simply), all in the name of "being pythonic" - IMO, _very_ bad advice.

Comment: @Izkata: How, exactly, is segregating various accelerators into logical groups increasing readability and increasing complexity?! Sure, using chain rather than simple concat *is* more complex, but I've stated reasons for doing so above (preferring ``+`` when called for).

Comment: @Izkata: Code should be self-documenting. In grouping them, it's more obvious from a code standpoint. You can also reorder trivially now (not that you'd need to in this particular context) based on reference rather than cut/pasting blocks of code. /Also/, if the accelerator list becomes long, segregating them /absolutely/ increases readability.

Comment: @DemianBrecht Downvote is based on the first half.  Your edit doesn't stand alone, and is meaningless without the comments (I didn't get what you were trying to explain with it until afterwards - I thought it was an addition to the first block of code) - I'll remove it if you clear up the answer.